# Hi, I want to save the collected data to file and then be able to read the data from the file

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a class Person and i want to store the relevant data in a file so that i can read and write from that file. Can anyone help?

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self,firstname, lastname,street,city,state,postcode):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.postcode = postcode

def getFirstName(self):
    return self.firstname

def getLastName(self):
    return self.lastname

def getStreet(self):
    return self.street

def getCity(self):
    return self.city

def getState(self):
    return self.state

def getPostcode(self):
    return self.postcode

def __str__(self):
    return 'Firstname: {}\nLastname: {}\nStreet: {}\nCity: {}\nState: {}\nPostcode: 
{}'.format(self.firstname,self.lastname,self.street,self.city, self.state,self.postcode)

firstname = input('Enter your firstname: ')
lastname = input('Enter your lastname: ')
street = input('Enter your street: ')
city = input('Enter your city: ')
state = input('Enter your state: ')
postcode = input('Enter your postcode: ')

person = Person(firstname,lastname,street,city,state,postcode)
print(person)
```

Comment: Hi @yazzy,
To solve your issue, most likely you don't need to share the full code. Please consider sharing the specific part your are struggling with. Ideally reproducible (error) by the community here.

Comment: Most likely this is a good start: https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/

Comment: i just want to know where i should add the add to write the data to file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file handling in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828214/file-handling-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The general idea would be to declare a file object with `open` in write mode (`w+`) and write a string object containing the data you want to it.

You would add this code after where successfully retrieving all the data and storing it into that string object.

`fileObject = open('[yourFileNameHere]', 'w+')`

Once you have this object you call its `.write` method to write strings to file.

```
personData = str(person)
f = open('./{}_Data.txt'.format(fileNameVar), 'w+')
f.write('{}'.format(personData); f.close()
```

It may, however, be a better idea to make a parsing function to create a string variable with a more appropriately formatted version of the data for saving to file.

Comment: my pleasure! hope it helped!